# Adding NS record to docker net's DNS server

Tags: docker, dns

When running a docker container inside a docker network (i.e. `docker network create $DOCKERNETNAME` and then using `--net=$DOCKERNETNAME` when running the container). The net creates a DNS server at 127.0.0.11.

I want to create a NS record inside this DNS server (the one running at 127.0.0.1), so I can have a separate DNS server inside the docker net for some fake domain. How can I do that?

Please note that all this is being done for educational purposes and has no other goal.